# Pipelight is enabled - still won't work

Tags: kubuntu

Hi there so I recently installed and enabled pipelight so that I could use Silverlight to watch SkyGo, however when I go onto SkyGo it still wants me to install Silverlight?

Any advice is welcomed, thank you. (Running Kubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Pipelight will not work on Chrome, Chromium or similar browsers. It works with Firefox. That may be the case.

Comment: I am using Firefox. :(

Comment: How did you install it? Did you try to test silverlight on other sites?

Comment: I installed it following the websites instructions and it's installed fine, and yes I've tried it with websites that need Flash as well

Comment: Please give a link to an instruction you used. Flash and silverlight are different. Did you try silverlight on other sites?

Comment: It's from the pipelight website which allows you to install both Flash and Silverlight.